# How to order the values in form control of angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need to order the values of array(of formarray) as per the values from an api.
I need to order the hobby array from,

```
"hobbies": [
    "eat",
    "sleep",
    "drink"
  ]
```

To,

```
"hobbies": [
    "sleep",
    "eat",
    "drink"
  ]
```

It should be ordered as per arranged hobbies,

```
ArrangedHobbies = [ {'eat': 1, 'sleep': 0, 'drink': 2}]
```

I need to arrange the values of hobbies array based on the order of ArrangedHobbies.

**what i have tried with es map,**

```
arrangeHobbyValues() {
   this.SignupForm.get('hobbies').map( x => { // tranform the value with map });
}
```

Here the full working [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-3ggxeo?file=app/app.component.ts) on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I added in the order you attempted, Eat > Sleep > Drink

`this.SignupForm.get('hobbies').value.sort().reverse();`

Comment: arrangedHobbies can be in any order.  I don't want to assign to any variable , I want the change the order within the formcontrol

Comment: There, try that now. should be ok

Comment: Brother, I don’t want to reverse but change the order as per the variable arrangedHobbies

Comment: it is, look at the console output. Same as your arranged hobbies. If you look at the form and the values, and then the hobbies inside... It is exactly how you wanted it: 

"hobbies": [
    "sleep",
    "eat",
    "drink"
  ]

Comment: That order is as per the order from database.

Answer (score -1):

In your control in blur call to arrageHobbyValues

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (blur)="arrangeHobbyValues()"
            [formControlName]="i">
```

Your arrangeHobbyValues can be like

```
  arrangeHobbyValues() {
    (this.SignupForm.get('hobbies') as FormArray).controls.sort((a,b)=>{
      let orderA:any=this.ArrangedHobbies[0][a.value] || 9999999;
      let orderB:any=this.ArrangedHobbies[0][b.value] || 9999999;
      return orderB-orderA
    })
```

But, is strange your "ArrangedHobbies", is an array of object ????

```
//if your arrangeHobies would be like
ArrangedHobbies = [ 'eat','sleep','drink']
//then
arrangeHobbyValues() {
    (this.SignupForm.get('hobbies') as FormArray).controls.sort((a,b)=>{
      let orderA:any=this.ArrangedHobbies.indexOf(a.value);
      let orderB:any=this.ArrangedHobbies.indexOf(b.value);
      if (orderA==-1)
          orderA=99999;
      if (orderB==-1)
          orderB=99999;
      return orderB-orderA
    })
```

Comment: can you implement this on stackblitz?

Comment: Sorry, I can not. just replace your function arrangeHobbyValues and change the line of the input, must be work :(